# 'textSelectionHandleColor' is deprecated and shouldn't be used

Tags: flutter, dart, themes, deprecated

in flutter , I have defined my custom theme like this

```
ThemeData(
  ...
  textSelectionColor: Colors.black,
  textSelectionHandleColor: Colors.white,
),
```

today, after dart update to version v1.23.0-4.0.pre, my code has found this problem.

> 'textSelectionHandleColor' is deprecated and shouldn't be used. Use TextSelectionThemeData.selectionHandleColor instead. This feature was deprecated after v1.23.0-4.0.pre..
> Try replacing the use of the deprecated member with the replacement.

but i have confused that how to use TextSelectionThemeData.

Does someone know how to do it? Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to use `textSelectionTheme` attribute and set it to `TextSelectionThemeData`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


void main() async {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo App',
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        theme: ThemeData(
          accentColor: Color(0xffBA379B).withOpacity(.6),
          primaryColor: Color(0xffBA379B),
          textSelectionTheme: TextSelectionThemeData(
            selectionColor: Color(0xffBA379B).withOpacity(.5),
            cursorColor: Color(0xffBA379B).withOpacity(.6),
            selectionHandleColor: Color(0xffBA379B).withOpacity(1),
          ),
        ),
        home: Home(),

    );
  }

}
```

Answer (score 7):

With the New `Flutter` version using `textSelectionHandleColor` directly is now deprecated.But `Flutter` added a new way to access it.

```
MaterialApp(
  title: 'My App',
  theme: ThemeData(
    primaryColor: Colors.red,
    textSelectionTheme: TextSelectionThemeData(
      selectionColor: Color(0xff35a19d),
      cursorColor: Color(0xff35a19d),
      selectionHandleColor: Color(0xff35a19d),
    ),
  ),
  home: MyWidget(),
);
```

You can acces like `Theme.of(context).textSelectionTheme.selectionHandleColor`